# no route matches when I submit a form search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm having troubles with a route in Rails. I'm trying to build a search form. I have an html form in the root_path (static_pages#index) view. I want when submit this form with the keywords that the results of spots which contain those tags are displayed in another view controlled by searchesController (searches#index). When I submit the console tells me 'no route matches get '/search' ' and I don't know why

This is the code of my routes

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get 'maps/:name' => 'maps#spot', :as => :spot_map


 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

 devise_scope :user do
   get 'sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_session
 end

 resources :users do
  resources :spots do
    resources :offers
  end
 end

 root 'static_pages#index'
 get 'search/:query' => 'searches#index', :as => "query"
 get 'search/spot/:id' => 'searches#show', :as => :search_result
 get 'tags/:tag' => 'static_pages#index', :as => "tag"
 get 'register' => 'static_pages#register', :as => :register
 get 'users/:id/profile' => 'profiles#show', :as => :user_profile

 get 'maps/homepage' => 'maps#homepage', :as => :homepage_map


 mount Attachinary::Engine => "/attachinary"
end
```

This is the code of the view (static_pages#index) where I have the html form. 
/static_pages/views/index.html.erb I've tried with action="/search" as well

```
<form action="query" method='get'>
    <div class="row collapse postfix-round">
      <div class="small-10 columns">
          <input id="home-placeholder" class="" type="search" name="query" placeholder="">      
      </div>
      <div class="small-2 columns">
        <input type="submit" class="button postfix" value="Buscar"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

This is the code of my controller

controllers/searches_controller.rb

```
class SearchesController

 def index
   @user = current_user if current_user
   @spots = Spot.full_text_search(params[:query])
 end 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the action to `<%= search_path %>`.

Comment: I know that would be a solution but I wanted to build the form in html. Thank you

Comment: Actually, your route is wrong `get 'search/:query'`. it should be just `get 'search', if you want the form to work like that.

Comment: Ok, I've found where was the problem. I tried with get 'search' as well and it didn't work. The mistake was really dum... I just had to put the inheritance of ApplicationController and it works fine...I'm sorry for such a stupid question but sometimes I assume things too fast. Thank you anyway